# Select option after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering, if it is possible to select 4th option from dropdown menu after redirect from other page and 5th option after redirect from another page.

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have control over the page with the select and the URL ?

Comment: I think you can do it by using a querystring and checking the Value of the querystring and then set the default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is simple html you can use:

HTML:

```
<div class="nu">
   <select>
     <option value="v1">Value 1</option>
     <option value="v2">Value 2</option>
     <option value="v3">Value 3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var url = service.getUrl();
if(url == 'www.google.com')
$("div.nu select").val("v2");
```

To get previous page url in js(Except IE):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ex=document.referrer;
document.write(ex);
</script>
```

Comment: What is service.getUrl? And you cannot rely on referrer being sent

Comment: service can be your own common class for your common functionsand get url can be the javascript that gets you the previous page url

Comment: Tha is not very obvious to a beginner. I could write such a thing easily, but now it looks like you found some jQuery class.

Comment: service.getUrl() is my example

Comment: of where you can put that actually returns the path.

Comment: Something with location.search or location.href would make it clearer.